# Customize the up button on ActionBar to include title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've been working with ActionBar for a while, but was constantly frustrated by its customizaton work. Also I've been playing with ActionBarSherlock and ActionBarCompat but finally get down to the later one.

I saw many apps combining the leftmost up button with the title into one clickable button on a ActionBar. How can that be achieved without supplying a custom layout for ActionBar? Is that a way to customize only the up button to include the title as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The up button is an `ImageView` not button. So you can not apply text using setText();

You can set an image with text to that ImageView.

Sample code:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.YourImage);
```

OR

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
ImageView imgHome=(ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
imgHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.YourImage);
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the up image and action bar title combining to be a button? I saw many apps (Facebook Messenger) behaving that way.